# Removed list instance and list NOT is deployed!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have deployed a list using visual studio. I have deleted the list instance and redeployed the list. Now, the list is not deploying! I have removed the the list and instance manually from the server. Any idea about this ? Ideally the list should be deployed without the instance, rt ?

Comment: How are you deploying it? Have you reactivated the feature if you are using that approach?

Comment: I'm deploying from my visual studio project. I'm currently working on that project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of completely deleting the ListInstance you can just exclude it from your feature so only the ListDefinition is deployed.

Comment: So, ListInstance is mandatory for a list ?